# Replaced rotary dimmers now lights not working

Tags: dimmer-switch

When I took off the old rotary dimmers, the hots were already spliced together with a black wire from each of the old switches.  I kept the spliced hots together and connected the blacks on the new switches.  My voltage tester shows power coming in and going up the travelers when I flip the switch (and not when switch is off).  Any ideas what’s wrong?  Pic is attached.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what is the red wire to nowhere for?

Comment: @dandavis red/white is typically used in 3-way configurations, which OP does not have.